# Ceedling project file does not recognize paths and libraries

Tags: c, unit-testing, testing, makefile, stm32

I wanted to use ceedling for unit testing C Code for STM32 family.
I installed it as shown on their page on [GitHub Ceedling](https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Ceedling) and run successfully the example tests.

The **project.yml** file I have modified the paths because I have a different path for header files (path: include) as the source files (path: src):

```
:paths:
  :test:
    - +:test/**
    - -:test/support
  :source:
    - build/STM32F2xx_StdPeriph_Driver/include/**
    - build/STM32F2xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/**
    - include/**
    - src/**
  :support:
    - test/support


  :defines:
    :commmon: &common_defines
      #Define for header files
      - STM32F2XX


:libraries:
  :placement: :end
  :flag: "${1}"  # or "-L ${1}" for example
  :common: &common_libraries []
  :test:
    - *common_libraries
      #toolchain of STM32F2
    - build/STM32F2xx_StdPeriph_Driver/include/**
    - build/STM32F2xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/**
    - build/STM32F2xx/include/
```

But somehow the path and libraries does not get recognized and I get error for unknown variables.

Is my **.yml** file wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for future readers, I switched to cppUTest. Its easy to use, and you have the power of cpp and the mocking is fantastic.